# UIToolbar UIBarButtonItem with both image and title has very dim text

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

My iPhone view adds some custom buttons to its toolbar. Each button has both an image and textual title, and is created like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *fooButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(fooButtonPressed:)];
fooButton.title=@"Foo";
```

The title's text displays very dim; it looks like it has an alpha of about 0.5. If I use the default UIToolBar barStyle, I can't read the text at all. When using UIBarStyleBlack I can read the text but it still looks very dim.

I also tried initWithTitle, and then set the image property; the results are identical.

Is there a way to brighten up the text? I am hoping for a look similar to a UITabBar whose items have both an image and title.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried changing the colour of the text?

Answer (score 7):

I was trying to use the UIBarButtonItem to display both an image and a button, but I'm pretty sure it's locked down to display one or the other. Using the basic idea from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903018/how-to-have-a-uibarbuttonitem-with-both-image-and-text) I came up with a solution using a UIButton and a background image. The biggest flaw of what I've done is that when the title text varies in size a lot, the background image stretches causing the rounded corners to look a little off.

CustomBarButtonItem.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface CustomBarButtonItem : UIBarButtonItem {}

- (id) initWithImage:(UIImage *)image title:(NSString *)title target:(id)target action:(SEL)action;

@end


@interface UIBarButtonItem (CustomBarButtonItem)

+ (UIBarButtonItem *) barButtonItemWithImage:(UIImage *)image title:(NSString *)title target:(id)target action:(SEL)action;

@end
```

CustomBarButtonItem.m

```
#import "CustomBarButtonItem.h"


@implementation CustomBarButtonItem

- (id) initWithImage:(UIImage *)image title:(NSString *)title target:(id)target action:(SEL)action {

    UIButton *barButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
    barButton.titleLabel.font = font;
    barButton.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1);
    barButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 5);
    [barButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [barButton setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [barButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [barButton setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [barButton setTitleShadowColor:[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [barButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar-button-item-background.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    barButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width + 15 + [title sizeWithFont:font].width, 30);

    if (self = [super initWithCustomView:barButton]) {
        self.target = target;
        self.action = action;
    }

    return self;
}

@end


@implementation UIBarButtonItem (CustomBarButtonItem)

+ (UIBarButtonItem *) barButtonItemWithImage:(UIImage *)image title:(NSString *)title target:(id)target action:(SEL)action {
    return [[[CustomBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image title:title target:target action:action] autorelease];
}

@end
```

Sample usage:

```
UIBarButtonItem *customButtonItem = [UIBarButtonItem barButtonItemWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"calendar.png"] title:@"Add to calendar" target:self action:@selector(addToCalendar)];
```

My background image for the button is:

[image]

Comment: This really helps the stretching:  UIImage *bImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar-button-item-background.png"];  UIImage *sbImage = [bImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:23 topCapHeight:0]; // use this for the background

Comment: Any idea how to put a border like a regular button? Only with an image?

Comment: @CarlosRicardo what do you mean by a "border like a regular button"? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My button doesn't have a border. Even if I force UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered

Comment: I don't think your question has to do with this thread, consider asking a new question? The way the border is created in this solution is simply using the background image.

Answer (score 2):

Johnus's solution is pretty useful.
But I've tried it and a little problem occured: ***the action was not sent to the bar button item***, so I've modified the initializer a little :

```
- (id) initWithImage:(UIImage *)image title:(NSString *)title target:(id)target action:(SEL)action {

    UIButton *barButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
    barButton.titleLabel.font = font;
    barButton.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1);
    barButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 5);
    [barButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [barButton setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [barButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [barButton setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [barButton setTitleShadowColor:[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [barButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar-button-item-background.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    barButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width + 15 + [title sizeWithFont:font].width, 30);

    if (self = [super initWithCustomView:barButton]) {
        self.target = target;
        self.action = action;
        // I've added just one line of code here
        [barButton addTarget:target
                      action:action
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are nice, however its often a little easier to use ***composition*** rather than ***inheritance*** with UIKit classes.

**Create a bar item like so:**

```
_accountBarItem =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[CustomerBarView buttonWithImage:
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"Account.png"] text:@"Account"]];
[_accountBarItem setTarget:self];
[_accountBarItem setAction:@selector(accountButtonPressed)];
```

**Implementation of Custom View with Image and Label**

```
@implementation CustomBarView

+ (instancetype)buttonWithImage:(UIImage*)image text:(NSString*)text
{
    CustomBarView* button = [[CustomBarView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];
    [button setText:text];
    [button setImage:image];
    return button;
}


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        _uiButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [self addSubview:_uiButton];

        _label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [_label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [_label setFont:[UIFont boldApplicationFontOfSize:9]];
        [_label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [_label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [self addSubview:_label];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)setText:(NSString*)text
{
    [_label setText:text];
}

- (void)setImage:(UIImage*)image
{
    [_uiButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}




- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [_uiButton setFrame:self.bounds];
    [_label setFrame:CGRectMake(2, self.height - 13, self.width - 4, 15)];
}

@end
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I got an image but no text, and the action did not fire when the button was tapped.