# How to have a bordered UIBarButton Item with both Image and Text - Like in Mail

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uiimage, uibarbuttonitem

In the *Mail* app on iPhone, when the user taps *Edit*, the toolbar shows two buttons, *Delete* and *Move*. These buttons have both image and text while appearing as bordered.

I tried to recreate this effect, but I have not really succeeded. Here's what I've tried:

- The obvious way of setting the `image` and `text` properties. This results in some weird button with the image on top and the text below it.
- Initialize the `UIBarButtonButton` with a custom view set to an instance of `UIButton` (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903018/how-to-have-a-uibarbuttonitem-with-both-image-and-text)). This button can then not be set to be bordered, instead it appears as a flat view (without shadows either).

I could obviously create a button and then add an `UIImageView` as a subview to the toolbar, but then I have to care about device rotation and some other stuff I would like to avoid. Also, I think Apple doesn't do it this way; when you select an email in *Mail* while in editing mode, the button label is updated with (-number-), which moves the image slightly to the left. It looks like the text and the image belong together.

So I wonder whether anybody did something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely these are UIButtons with stretchable image backgrounds. That's how I would do it.