# UIToolbar xib xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitoolbar

I am trying to create a custom UIToolbar that I can add to multiple views,  I don't want to do this programmatically so I am using xib to design a UIToolbar.  Do I need to wrap this in a UIView and a View Controller?  ViewController.m is the root view controller.  This is just a simple project I am just trying out some stuff

[image: UIToolbar XIB]

[image: Adding CustomToolbar to the Root UIView]

Comment: did you ever get answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this so:

1. create ToolBar.xib file, delete UIView and add UIToolbar
2. create ToolBar.swift file, add code, like shown, and make outlets
3. for .xib in "Identity and Type" put Name "ToolBar.swift"

[image: /Users/Igor/Desktop/Снимок экрана 2016-01-05 в 03.34.33.png]

4. In your root View Controller put this code in ViewDidLoad:

   ```
   let toolBar = UINib(nibName: "ToolBar", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil).first as! ToolBar
   toolBar.hidden = true
   self.navigationController!.view.addSubview(toolBar)
   self.navigationController!.toolbarItems = toolBar.items
   ```
5. In all View Controllers put in ViewDidLoad:

   ```
   self.toolbarItems = self.navigationController!.toolbarItems
   ```
6. ToolBar.swift:

   ```
   import UIKit

   class ToolBar: UIToolbar {

       override init(frame: CGRect) {
           super.init(frame: frame)
       }

       required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
           super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       }

       @IBAction func item1Pressed(sender: AnyObject) {
           print("item 1 pressed")
       }

       @IBAction func item2Pressed(sender: AnyObject) {
           print("item 2 pressed")
       }

       @IBAction func item3Pressed(sender: AnyObject) {
           print("item 3 pressed")
       }

       @IBAction func item4Pressed(sender: AnyObject) {
           print("item 4 pressed")
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: in 4 point lot of errors. Remove second line (will hide the toolbar), the third line is wrong because it will add the view at top of navigationController, the correct one is:
self.navigationController!.toolbar.addSubview(toolBar). The four line is useless.