# Custom back button is tons slower than native back button

Tags: ios

Why is there a pregnant pause between custom back button touch up
and an action delivered?

back button was setup using abbood recipe here

[How can I have a UIBarButtonItem with both image and text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903018/how-can-i-have-a-uibarbuttonitem-with-both-image-and-text)

but it's not specific to this method of back button setup.
I remember it was always slow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that when you put a custom button inside a UIBarButtonItem you have a button within a button. So the runtime has to figure out what exactly the tap belongs to and what kind of tap it is.

Comment: Seems like a common pattern here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903018/how-can-i-have-a-uibarbuttonitem-with-both-image-and-text

Comment: stuffing a custom non button uiview with isuserinteractionenabled set to false into  UIBarButtonItem constructor taking a custom view brings another problem: target action on UIBarButtonItem itself is not invoked