# UIBarButtonItem with image and text, and a border?

Tags: ios

I would like to create a UIBarButtonItem with an icon and text.  I've seen [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903018/how-to-have-a-uibarbuttonitem-with-both-image-and-text) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533238/uitoolbar-uibarbuttonitem-with-both-image-and-title-has-very-dim-text) but when you set the background image it doesn't draw a border.

I don't really want to draw a border (that looks like the "Plain" style one) with my icon on it.  Is there another way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the first solution you linked to you will notice the following line

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton= [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:chatButton] autorelease];
```

You can initialize a button with whatever view you would like. You can make a button with any (acceptable) view inside it.

eg.

```
// GRAPHICAL BUTTON FRAMEWORK
     UIButton* btton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     [btton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
     [btton addTarget:self action:@selector(SOMEROUTINE) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [btton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SOME IMAGE"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     UIBarButtonItem* remix = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btton] autorelease];
```

Hope that helps!