# UIBarButtonItem with style UIBarButtonItemStylePlain and with both text and image

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uibarbuttonitemstyle

I'm trying to generate an UIBarButtonItem with style:UIBarButtonItemStlyePlain, and also with both text and image.

The best solutions I found in this site ([this one for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533238/uitoolbar-uibarbuttonitem-with-both-image-and-title-has-very-dim-text)) didn't let me set the style as Plain. In fact, this solution only makes a buttonitem with no stlye, but with both text and image.

That's a good progress to solve what I want, but is there a way to add programmatically that plain stlye?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a UIBarButtonItem with a custom view that has both an image and label.  You can ask the system for the UIBarButtonItemStlyePlain style properties using UIAppearance protocols.

Example:

`UIColor *textColor = [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] titleTextAttributesForState:UIControlStateNormal][UITextAttributeTextColor];`